# Node-red: get value from msg.payload and save it inside variable

Tags: javascript, node-red

how can I take the value from msg.payload and put it inside variable then I can use this variable in different functions (node-red)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What code have you written already? Please have a read of [this guide on producing code for a good quality question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then include and mark up your code in your question. Cheers!

Comment: We need a better picture of what exactly you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to a function node:

`global.set("Variable_name_here",msg.payload);`

This will store the `msg.paylog` (received on the input of the node) to a global variable that can be used at any time, from any flow.

In order to use the variable add this to a function node:
`var M =global.get("Variable_name_here");`

This will set the global variable value to the local variable M, to be used in your node.

Answer (score 0):

Each `msg` is just a javascript object, and using `msg.payload` to contain the data a node operates on is really more of a convention than a hard rule (ie: most of the nodes in node-red look for data in the `msg.payload` field).  However, you can also attach data to any other property in the `msg` object, with the exception of the `id` field.

When you pass that message from one node to another, you can then access your stored data using the `msg` object.

If you store a query in `msg.query`, for example, you can access it in a subsequent node in the flow by just accessing the `msg.query` object.